# Warning: Attempt to present ---- whose view is not in the window hierarchy! in Swift and one var not transferred

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have an app with a number of StoryBoards and numerous segues similar to the one below - all work fine except for the one I am showing below. Two problems:
1. I get the warning 
2. one var does not get transferred

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "goToDetails") {
        let nav3 = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
        let svc3 = nav3.topViewController as! ActivityDetailTableViewController
        svc3.majCat = majCat //Pass the category
        svc3.subCat2 = subCat
        print(subCat)
        svc3.me = me
    }
```

the var subCat is the problem - print shows that it has a value before calling ActivityDetailTableViewController
but then disappears - I have tried everything - renaming etc nothing helps - the other 2 vars are fine.

Comment: The code is not complete. var subcat is not declared anywhere.

Comment: As warning says add the controller in window hierarchy using `addChildViewController` method. Secondly, assign the values when the ActivityDetailTableViewController view is loaded in memory.

Comment: var subCat is declared in another part of the code and print(subCat) prints it value - but it disappears in the next VC.
I am not clear on how to "addChildViewController".
It is also strange to me that both majCat & me appear without an issue in the next VC

Comment: One thing I have noticed that is different about this VC compared to ones that work fine is that I set these up as view controllers with a table delegate .

Answer (score 0):

At this point in your code the view controller's view has only been created but not added to any view hierarchy. If you want to present along with loading of  your view controller then implementation of it in `viewWillAppear(_:)` or `viewDidAppear(_:)` to be safest.

> When a view controller tries to open (present/push) another view
>   controller from viewDidLoad (before its own view appears/loaded), it will show such
>   warning.

See, for more details on: [UIViewControllerTransition](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontrollertransitioncoordinator)

Answer (score 0):

The problem of the "missing" var was the result of a simple mistake - one easily made - I Segued from a table row and not from the story board and my prepare for Segue looked like:
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any!) {

so the table row segue executed before the UIStoryboardSegue!
The issue of the warning is still there - I am sure its because my tableview is imbedded in a View.